# Popup page with Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have calendar in popup page so it is hide when I choose date the problem is when I clicking into next month or previous month the popup page will be close so I need to check if the clicking into day or month any help please.

```
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEndDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png"
                        OnClick="imgEndDate_Click" Width="28px" Height="28px" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlEndCalendar" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BackColor="White"
                        Height="250px" Width="330px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <asp:Calendar ID="calEndDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black"
                            BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black"
                            Height="250px" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" Width="330px" OnSelectionChanged="calEndDate_SelectionChanged">
                            <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Height="8pt" />
                            <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#333399" ForeColor="White" />
                            <TitleStyle BackColor="#333399" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt"
                                ForeColor="White" Height="12pt" />
                            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="White" />
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgEndDate"
                        PopupControlID="pnlEndCalendar" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: Please post some example code.

Comment: I post the source code. If know I check if the pressing is month or date?

Comment: @user3544536 when you change month calendar control do postback and modalpopupextender close popup, so possibly if you wrap your calendar in update panel problem will be solved

Comment: All the page in update panel.

Comment: @user3544536 wrap calendar in separate updatepanel

Comment: I did it in separate page just this code in update panel and it does not work !!!

Comment: possibly you need [AjaxControlToolkit.Calendar](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) instead implementing this functionality yourself?

Comment: can you provide code for your updatepanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[asp:Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar(v=vs.90).aspx) is server side control that implement `IPostBackEventHandler`, so on events from this control sending postback.

When you change month - raise event [VisibleMonthChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visiblemonthchanged(v=vs.90).aspx) and send postback.

When sending postback - parent `UpdatePanel` update it content, so `ModalPopupExtender` hide popup.

For solving you need wrap calendar in `UpdatePanel` and setup trigger for main `UpdatePanel` or update main `UpdatePanel` manually in your `Calendar.OnSelectionChanged` handler.

So you need change your markup like this

```
....
<UpdatePanel ID="main" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
    ....
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgEndDate" ... />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlEndCalendar" runat="server" ...>
            <UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>                
                    <asp:Calendar ID="calEndDate" runat="server"
                                  OnSelectionChanged="calEndDate_SelectionChanged" ...>
                        ....
                    </asp:Calendar>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="imgEndDate" PopupControlID="pnlEndCalendar" ...>
                </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
    ....
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="calEndDate" EventName="selectionchanged" />
    </Triggers>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Where *Main* `UpdatePanel` is UpdatePanel for all page